# Should forcing open doors be Strength or Strength (Athletics)

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, ability-scores

According to RAW, should forcing stuck/locked/barred doors open be a Strength check, or a Strength (Athletics) check?

As I read the description of the Strength ability and the Athletics skill in the rules, it seems that brute force checks, such as pushing/shoving/kicking or pulling open a stuck, heavy or locked door should be a simple Strength check, with the Athletics skill applying only to things that involve more coordination such as jumping, climbing, or swimming.

However, in the published Dungeons & Dragons adventures, examples are inconsistent. Other than the Starter Set, where all door checks are just Strength and all Athletics checks involve climbing or other more complicated activity, other supplements seem to contain a mix of Strength or Strength (Athletics) to force open doors, seemingly at random within the same adventure.

For example, in Curse of Strahd area K74, opening the 5-foot-submerged iron gate to a row of cells requires a DC 10 Strength (Athletics) check, but opening the 5-foot submerged locked/barred gate to any particular cell is a DC 25 Strength check. The only difference is the latter is locked. But then in K78 opening the locked door is a DC 25 Strength (Athletics) check, so being locked/barred isn't the determinant.

What do the rules specify should be the standard check to force open a door, gate, portcullis, etc.? When do they say Athletics skill should apply, if ever? I'm not asking about DM preference (because I realize any DM can vary any rule any time they feel the need), but what the RAW and RAI state, and if there is any rules-based explanation for the noted exceptions.

Comment: Obviously, operating a door is an Intelligence (door operation) check. ;)

Comment: @Medix2 I looked through several and it seems pretty random. But I could put in one set of contrasting examples.

Comment: This question is *not* opinion based, we have numerous similar questions: "[What ability should be used when resisting Intimidation?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/73089)" and "[What skill or skills should apply to an appraisal check in 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/57130)" and "[What Skill Checks should be used in a Bargaining or Bartering situation?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/74653)" to name only three

Comment: @enkryptor: [Don't answer in comments.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/33569) As mentioned by the others, if the answer is "it's up to the DM" (e.g. because the rules don't specify a single "correct" way to resolve this), that's still an answer; it doesn't make the question primarily opinion-based. See this FAQ on Meta: [Does “Ask the DM / GM” equate to “Primarily opinion based?”](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7353/33569)

Comment: That said, another relevant meta: [We should talk about the word “should”](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9344/33569). Are you asking "What do the rules state about this?"/"Is there a single right way to handle this, per the rules?" - or are you asking "Since the rules are inconsistent, how does each individual DM handle this inconsistency?" The former is not primarily opinion-based; the latter generally is, since there's no way to determine a single "right" answer (i.e. every answer is potentially equally valid).

Comment: @Medix2 Opinion based answers are perfectly fine if backed by expertise or direct experience. All of the Opinion based answers seem to be of that nature.

Comment: A point on terminology used in this question: A "Strength (Athletics) check" *is* a kind of "Strength check". One is a subset of the other. The more conventional way to pose this question using the language of the 5e rules would be "Does Athletics proficiency apply to a Strength check to force open a door?"

Comment: I see what you mean, @Blckknght, but I I am using the wording as it is presented in the published adventures, such as this quote from Candlekeep Mysteries: "force open the hatch with a successful DC 25 Strength (Athletics) check"

Comment: Any of these answers worthy of being accepted?  Is there a particular part of the question you don't think was adequately addressed?

Answer (score 19):

### RAW Forcing open a door is a Strength Check

Comparing Strength with Strength (Athletics) as described in the PHB, we can conclude that forcing open a door should be a Strength check.

Let's start with Strength checks.  The PHB says (175/176 - emphasis mine) says

> A Strength check can model any attempt to lift, push, pull, or **break something**, to force your body through a space, or to otherwise apply brute force to a situation...
> The DM might also call for a Strength check when you try to accomplish tasks like
> the following:
> • **Force open a stuck, locked, or barred door**
> • Break free of bonds
> • Push through a tunnel that is too small
> • Hang on to a wagon while being dragged behind it
> • Tip over a statue
> • Keep a boulder from rolling

We note first that Strength checks are explicitly called out as being used for forcing doors open, as well as breaking things in general.  On a more subtle note, we can see that they reflect short bursts of 'brute force', **single events** that either succeed or fail immediately.

On Strength (Athletics) checks, however, the PHB (175 - emphasis mine) says:

> The Athletics skill reflects aptitude in **certain kinds** of Strength checks...Your Strength (Athletics) check covers **difficult situations you encounter while climbing, jumping, or swimming.** Examples include the following activities:
> • You attempt to climb a sheer or slippery cliff, avoid hazards while scaling a wall, or cling to a surface while something is trying to knock you off.
> • You try to jump an unusually long distance or pull off a stunt midjump.
> • You struggle to swim or stay afloat in treacherous currents, storm-tossed waves, or areas of thick seaweed.  Or another creature tries to push or pull you underwater
> or otherwise interfere with your swimming.

By their nature, Athletics checks are not used for *events*, but rather for ***situations***.  There is some complex process that you are attempting over a period of time, and the DM calls for a check to see if you can pass the most difficult or dangerous part of the process.  [Grammarians should note the shift from the simple tense descriptions of Strength checks to the progressive tenses of the Strength (Athletics) checks.]

Two people with equal Strengths might be equally good at the "burst strength" required to tip over a statue.  But, by virtue of their Athletic training, a person with the Athletics skill would have the stamina, focus, balance, and determination needed for a long climb up a sheer cliff that someone with untrained raw strength would lack.

Applying this background understanding to the specific question of opening doors, we can assume that most doors would be subject to a single instance of burst strength, a single event of applying enough force to break through their structural integrity (lock, latch, bar, hinges, or what have you).  A portcullis has a certain weight - if the character can lift the weight in a single burst (Strength), the portcullis can be lifted.

### But there are situations in which Athletics could rightly be considered

A Strength (Athletics) check might be properly called for when opening the door or lifting the portcullis is no longer an *event* but has become a prolonged and difficult *situation*.  For example -  the gate of the palisade is thick and barred from the other side, and no simple burst of strength will sunder it.  You can eventually chop through it with your axe, but can you do that before the orcs arrive?

You can lift the portcullis; you are strong enough for that, but can you hold it open for several rounds while the rest of the party makes it under and you are being subjected to missile and spell fire?

Comment: "My special guard training taught me how to break down doors. We practised" - Athletics check

Comment: I definitely agree that opening a door should be a Strength check (the rules you cited are convincing and clear), but I'm hearing in your answer that the important distinction between when Athletics and straight Strength checks are called for is the duration of the attempt (given your use of "short events" and "prolonged and difficult situation"). Is that your intent? Because I have trouble reconciling this with the fact that some Athletics checks are for things that must happen in a single round (e.g. PHB. p. 175 "Athletics... examples include... try[ing] to jump an unusually long distance.")

Comment: @Gandalfmeansme Not the duration in and of itself, but rather how complicated is the process.  A Strength check is for 'one thing' whereas an Athletics check is for the most difficult part of a complex series of things.   A jump, for example, might take less than your full movement on a single turn - but 'pulling off a stunt midjump' is the hardest part of a series of events and merits an Athletics check.  The longer the duration of the activity, the higher the likelihood it is complicated enough to call for an Athletics check rather than simply Strength.

Answer (score 9):

The Angry GM brings up this particular example in his article on Ability Checks. https://theangrygm.com/being-in-flex-able/

Since you’re asking this question, I highly recommend reading the full overview of ability checks, skills, and a seasoned review of the rules and some recommendations.

The short version is that he recommends asking for just the strength check first. But if the player has a reasoning for how Athletics (or any other skill) would apply in the particular circumstance, he would let the player add that.

Additionally, for reference, in The Angry GM’s free 5e module The Fall of Silverpine Watch he does not call out Athletics as a likely skill to work with forcing doors open.

Comment: That's how I would play it, and when my player says they'd like to apply Athletics to the roll, as DM I'd say "okay, no."

Answer (score 6):

I would (and do) apply the Athletics skill.  Characters don't get a lot of skills, so it's an investment to choose Athletics as one of the (about) 4 you get.  So it should be of some use.

The entire point of the Athletics skill is that you are better at physical tasks,  Opening (stuck, locked, etc.) doors is a physical task.  So if a character has invested in the skill, he should get the benefit of that.

Comment: That approach treats the Athletics skill as nothing more than a +2 on all Strength ability checks, regardless of what you're actually trying to do, making Athletics merely a generic Strength boost. No other skill works like this.

Comment: <shrug>  And ... ?  No other skill is the *only* one for that stat.  Strength is already one of the less important stats, and the only one that I ever use as a dump stat when building characters.

Comment: well, Strength doesn't have other skills, but it boosts attack and damage rolls, unlike any other stat but Dexterity (and unlike Dexterity, applies to ALL melee and thrown weapons), as well as the main stat for escaping all kinds of grapple/restrain conditions caused by monster & hazards. Plus determining jump distance & carry capacity.

Comment: @PhilB and Erich: You're welcome to disagree with one another, but there's no need to be rude. Comments are for asking for clarification or suggesting an improvement to the answer, not for arguing or attacking one another. If you disagree with the answer and have a competing perspective, you're welcome to post that as your own answer. Beyond that, you can judge the answer by voting on it accordingly.

Comment: Tell that to the people who like to comment on people's answers not to clarify, but to argue.  It happens a lot around here.  I wasn't attacking; I was defending from an arguer.  And yet it's my post that gets removed, and not that of the guy who came on to argue and attack.

Comment: @PhilB: The first 2 or 3 comments are useful debate, IMO, that bring up interesting points to consider about whether someone might want to use this ruling or not.  Presumably the deleted comment wasn't as useful, or if you think it was, then try again without being rude.  I don't see any hostility in Erïch's comments, not that I'd describe as an "attack", just normal criticism.  Would you rather people downvoted *without* explaining what they thought was a problem in your answer, so you didn't have the chance to modify your answer to include more justification?

Comment: dexterity can also be used to escape a grapple (oh and the acrobatics skill applies there). Dex applies to way more skills than strength. Allow strong people trained in athletics the chance to bust down doors easily. There is no other skill for this. Sure you could attack the door, but even a strong charcter would need several rounds to bust through that way. In my opinion that's one of the benefits of athletics, being able to more reliably break the door down much more quickly.

Comment: if you look at other skills, nothing is used more often than perception, probably followed by stealth. Acrobatics comes up way more often than athletics too. Allowing athletics to apply to doors is in no way game-breaking, or even bring it on par with those arguably more useful skills. Heck, even with athletics, and caharcter with dex and thieves tools proficiency is still going to be better at getting through locked doors. For the few doors that aren't locked but are truly stuck, let the athletics character shine.

Comment: @PeterCordes -- One explanation is fine.  Then I can agree or disagree with their reasoning, and respond once.  Persisting in arguing about it is not welcome, and as stated is not what comments are for.  If he's got a different answer, he can post his different answer, and quit trying to negate mine.

Answer (score 3):

I would allow either, on physical (real-world) grounds.

If you have the brute strength, then fine, use it, smash down the door on a plain Strength check.

If you have specific training for using and controlling your strength, then use that—a Strength (Athletics) check—to break down the door. Take advantage of the proficiency bonus you get from your training. Physically (in the real world) this would correspond to developing your core strength, not just arm or leg strength.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I always let people add their applicable skills. It makes more sense that someone who trains in lifting things (which is part of athletics) would be better at lifting a portcullis than someone who isn't. They would probably also have an easier time opening a stuck door. If someone puts one of their limited number of trained skills into something, I'm going to give them the benefit of using it if it makes sense to do so. That is just my personal GM style though.